# Adobe Reader out of memory error after Windows wake up

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, sleep, pdf-reader, out-of-memory

I opened a PDF file by Adobe Reader. I put Windows on sleep mode. After I woke Windows up, Adobe Reader shows only some recent pages (all of other pages are blank) and reports out of memory error on other pages. Is there a way to fix this problem?

**EDIT**

The problem occurs when the PDF files are in external hard drive. There is no problem with files in internal storage device. I tried Windows 8 Reader app, Foxit Reader and SumatraPDF, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 2):

its sounds like bug in the program itself and not related to windows can you have you tried different PDF reader?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. It's a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that upon wakeup the external isn't coming online before Adobe looks for the files on it. Try this: Use Process Explorer to suspend Reader, sleep, wake up, wait until your external is recognized (you can browse files on it with Explorer), resume Reader. I'll bet the problem goes away. This won't give you a solution (you'll still likely have to close and open the file, maybe Reader itself, to see all your pages) but at least it will tell you if the problem is in Reader.

Answer (score 0):

I have been plagued for a long time by PDFs from network shares that appear blank or give memory errors after resuming from hibernation. I used to quit Reader altogether and reload the documents, but recently I found another workaround:

Make a change to the PDF, for example by adding a sticky note or highlighting text. Then click on File -> Revert. Reader will then reload the document from the external HD or network share.

It probably only works for files that allow commenting, but that is the case in most files I work with. Make sure you have the Reader toolbar configured to show the commenting tools.